# Getting Pagespeed 100/100 can get you penalized in Google?

Tags: seo, web-development, page-speed, penalty

I am a developer on a website, and I am trying every possible way to get highest score 100/100 on Google pagespeed.

But it comes out that this sanbox checker tools show as penalized from time to time - http://pixelgroove.com/serp/sandbox_checker/

Is it related or my SEO guy at company is not aware of something else instead of the site itself or can be because of his SEO activities?

Comment: Describe his SEO "activities"

Comment: ＠zippyv, no idea. I suspect he and his community is not so white but he denied.

Comment: If he is unable to descibe how he works than you shouldn't use his services anymore. If he is spamming other websites to promote your website you will get punished by Google.

Comment: we have 3 member in IT team and he is incharge of SEO and marketing emails. He is there before I joined company and I cant easily taken over his job.

Comment: You have to take these online tools with a LOT of salt. None of them are absolute authorities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are completely independent areas:

- On pagespeed testing are only things measured, which have to do with load time, like amount and size of static assets, time to first byte and the like.
- Sandbox checker makes only queries to the Google search engine to get checked, whether the domain is in general present in SERP (not banned), whether something beside of the homepage exists in index (not penalized).

Indeed, I don't know, how this tool measures the third parameter (sandboxed). But if I would do it, so I would make a query to any tool like SimilarWeb to get to know, whether the traffic extremely dropped in the last time.

Anyway, there are two completely different areas.